# If $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$ and $\infty$ is a regular point, then $f=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$ and $\infty$ is a regular point. Show $f$ is identically $0$.

I write the Laurent expansion about infinity which is the Laurent expansion of $g(z)=f(1/z)$ about $0$, and the principal part is $0$. Compare it with the taylor expansion of $f(z)$ at $0$ plugging in $1/z$, then I have all the coefficients in Taylor expansion is $0$. Am I doing in the right way?

Comment: what is the meaning of  $\infty$ is a regular point

Comment: There are trivial counterexamples (unless your "regular point" means something very different from what it sounds like).

Comment: Wouldn't a constant function suffice? Not just the zero function